# Gradle build takes too long through jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, build, continuous-integration

My Java/Springboot project build is very slow via Jenkins with Gradle plugin. When try checkout manually and try the below :

> gradle build

Build runs very fast ! around 3 minutes , otherwise will take around 29 minutes.

The Build step i do via Jenkins is the same actually,

[image]

The SVN code checkout part is fast on both method. Only the build part is slow. What could be the issue ?

Comment: you should be able to get the jenkins logs to verify what it is doing at that time

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `--profile` argument to the gradle command line to write a report to `build/reports/profile`. From that you'll be able to see where all the time is being spent. See [profiling a build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:profiling_build)

Comment: This actually helped !    
:compileJava 8m59.97s 
:test 8m38.40s    
:compileTestJava 6m52.34s   
:startScripts 6m26.26s     
:distZip 3.820s .   

 Looks like time is even for all activities!

Comment: Maybe the source files are on a different machine to the gradle process so everythings happening across the network (eg network drive)? Perhaps the heap size is too small and it's GC'ing the whole time?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is the download time of artifacts.

When you run 2 builds , does the second one run faster ? 
Try to remove the .gradle folder from your local machine and build. How much time it took ?

Are you using an artifact repository - artifactory / Nexus ?

Comment: Using JFrog artifactory, artifact download occurred only once , cached on the later builds(additional +15 Mins for the first time)

Every build takes almost that same time ~ 29mins.

Comment: Are you using the timestamp plugin ? It will show you which task spend this time. So first build takes 45 minutes and the second 29 minutes on Jenkins machine ? And on your machine it's only 3 ?  Are you running the same gradle version ? And the same command ? Can you run manually the build on Jenkins slave to check its duration ?

Comment: Not using timestamp plugin.

first build in Jenkins: 45 Minutes (additional time for artifact download which is expected)

Rest of the build : 29 Minutes.

On the same build server, On the same jenkins's workspace, with the same gradle version, through command line ~3 minutes.

Comment: What is the command line that you used ? What is the command in the build ( check the log ) and add the timestamp plugin to understand what take the time

Comment: Time stamp plugin is not required for gradle. 
-profile flag is used instead. :compileJava 8m59.97s :test 8m38.40s :compileTestJava 6m52.34s :startScripts 6m26.26s :distZip 3.820s